Merging disk partitions in Ubuntu
I have created disk partition as in the image below. How can I merge the partitions ext_29 and ext_30 to make it a singe partition. I cannot find a merge option in the gparted window Is there any way to merge both of these into the linux root partition (111.72 GB shown in the image)


This question is similar to: How do I merge two ext4 partitions? and https://askubuntu.com/questions/841959/how-do-i-merge-two-ext4-partitions. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note little key icons show mounted partitions. You cannot edit mounted partitions. Generally you use a live installer which has gparted or a gparted live flash drive, but if gpt and not system partitions, you may be able to unmount p4 and then work on the partitions. Before making any major changes be sure to have good backups of all your data.
